# Is there a way to emit a warning if an overriding method don't call the overridden implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Is there a function attribute (standard or compiler extension) that emits a warning if an overriding method doesn't call the overridden  method?

Like this:

```
class A
{
protected:
    [[please_call]]
    virtual void foo() { /* ... */ };
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void foo() override {}
    // WARNING: B::foo() does not call A::foo()
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [non-virtual interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing like that.

Comment: Overriding functions that doesn't call the parent class function is a very valid thing, it would not make sense for the compiler to warn about it. Perhaps it could be caught by a static analyzer? Or you need code-reviews to catch that.

Comment: would be an error ok too?

Comment: This should not be a warning in the general case, `Derived::foo()` is not required to call `Base::foo()` in C++. When you override a function, you're free to do anything you want. If for a specific use-case you need that, you need to add that warning yourself (for example add a log message in the beginning of `Derived::foo()` implementation).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number an error would be ok too. I toyed with the idea of non-virtual inheritance, the issues being: (1) my A class also inherits from a third-party class I don't own and can't change, (2) non-virtual inheritance doesn't play well with multiple inheritance (I would need to define a new virtual method each time and make the previous one final).

Comment: The `[[lonely parent]]` idiom?

Comment: you already got the answer I was fishing for. I just wonder if you ask for a warning because there can be exceptions, or if it is ok to make sure that all derived `foo` do call `A::foo`. Btw there is no inheritance in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to use another function in the base class and the call the virtual function in that function.  That would look like

```
class Base
{
public:
    void doFoo() { Base::doFooImpl(); doFooImpl(); }
private:
    virtual void doFooImpl() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    void doFooImpl() override { std::cout << "Dervied\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.doFoo();
}
```

output:

```
Base
Derived
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cb048aaa76dd89e)

Comment: at every inheritance level, you'll need to repeat this pattern. not really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do something like that.

```
class A
{
  public:
    class fooRet
    {
      fooRet() {}
      friend class A;
    };    
  protected:
    virtual fooRet foo() { /* ... */ return {} };
};
```

Now any overrider of `foo` must return a `fooRet`, but there is no way to get one other than by calling `A::foo()`.